# A ridiculously complicated business days/hours/minutes sla calculation to figure out

Tags: algorithm, datetime

Okay,  I've been going round in circles for the last 2 days trying to figure this one out.

I am working on a system that handles 'cases'. Each case has a type and each type has an associated SLA which can be specified in days, hours or minutes.  In addition to this there is an administrative function which allows the user to specify the start and end time of the working day and which days in the week are worked.  I should point out that working hours are  the same for every working day.  So for example, the working hours might be 9:00 to 13:30 on a Monday, Wednesday and Thursday.  I'm not going to bother including holidays in this function just yet...It's tough enough as it is!

**Given the days and hours that are worked and the SLA,.. how can I calculate the date and time when the case breaches it's SLA.**

I get the feeling that since the minimum resolution of an SLA is set in minutes, I'll need to convert everything to minutes first.  Obviously the day/time that the case is created will have to be taken into account too.  Other than those two nuggets of wisdom I'll be honest,...I'm floundering :-)

Absolutely any help would be hugely appreciated on this.  It's probably also worth mentioning that if there is a library out there to do this I'm happy to use it and move on.  C# is my preferred language but any solution would be great

Lots of thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you're 90% of the way there already with the realisation that you should just normalise everything to consistent units.  What specific issue are you still facing?

Comment: It's a little difficult to articulate the problem but consider the possibility that they work for one hour on a Thursday.  An SLA of 7 hours would result in a completion time of 7 weeks in the future.  The problem is that I'm not sure how to find the ammount of non working time given an SLA and add what to do with it when I've got it!

Comment: As you say that you're not concerned about holidays (yet), is it fair to say that there's a fixed number of working minutes per week for a given SLA?  If so, can you just divide SLA time by minutes-per-week, and then sort out the remainder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would have a list of days in the week and the number of working minutes in each day. Loop through the list subtracting working minutes from the task until it is 0, while adding a full day's worth of minutes to a "real-world time to completion" variable.

If the task's remaining minutes are less than a day's working minutes then add those to the time to completion variable instead.

That tells me how may minutes between task start and task completion, which can be compared to the type's SLA.

Not sure if it's the best way but it's a start :) Hope it helps

Comment: Totally on the money.  Thanks very much.